# Chart js does not load on page

Tags: javascript, dom, chart.js

I have the following Django code, it has a list of cards that are automatically generated and each card should be generated a Chart. However, this chart is being generated only on the first card, not the others. What can I be doing wrong?

Check out my code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
Listagem de Linhas
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    {% for row in list %}
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <h5 class="card-header">{{row.description}}</h5>
                <!--<img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'img/gauge.png' %}" width="100" height="200" alt="Card image cap">!-->
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                <a href="{% url 'row_details' pk=row.pk %}" class="btn botao-detalhar">Detalhar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block scripts %}
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'doughnut',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                backgroundColor: ['rgb(0, 99, 132)', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'orange'],
                borderColor: '#fff',
                data: [5, 10, 5, 2, 20],
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
            circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
            rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
            cutoutPercentage: 90
        }
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

[outpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snWGz.png)

Comment: You use `getElementById`which returns only the first element. That's why only your first chart is displayed.

Try adding some class on your divs and mapping `getElementByClassName` to intsanciate your charts

Answer (score 0):

You have `id="myChart"` assigned inside of your forloop and `getElementById('myChart')` to modify the canvas. However, **ids should be unique**. I ran into this problem with HTML myself a while back. Your HTML, CSS, and JS will treat an id as unique and only work with the first occurrence that they find. That's why only the first card's chart is being rendered.

Your options are to to use a variable in the id to make each of them unique, E.G `id="myChart-{{ forloop.counter }}`, or to switch to using classes. You're probably better off using classes for this instance.